# how to make my point become visible and become haircross point?

Tags: opengl-es

How to make the crosshair point in OpenGL ES? After I get the coordinate of my object by using glTranslatef, I want to make my point become visible and in the crosshair style. How to do it? thanks. Any references of the sorce code?

Answer (score 0):

Draw two perpendicular `GL_LINE`s centered around wherever you want your cross-hair to be.

Comment: do u have example code for this part? I forgotten How to write bcos in openGL ES there is different way of declaration I think..thanks:)